# Finding the sum of unique dates

Tags: r

I am very new to R, and am working with a data set of payment details from a website I run. I have a data frame which includes the following columns:

```
¦  Date ¦ Amount ¦ Type
```

Each row is an individual payment with differing amounts. I would like to find a way, without looping through the 25,000 or so payments, to find the total payment amount on each day in the data set.

I have tried `sum(sub$Amount[sub$Date == unique(sub$Date)])` but that throws the following error:

```
Warning message:
In sub$Date == unique(sub$Date) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

As I said, I'm very new to R, so I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but can't work out how to do this without a loop.

Comment: Post output of dput(head(sub)) for getting better help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using base R:

```
with(sub, tapply(Amount, Date, sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ddply from the plyr library:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(sum, .(Date), summarize, sum=sum(Amount))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sub)[, sum(Amount), by = Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar `dplyr` solution :

```
library(dplyr)
sub %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(sum=sum(Amount))
```